bxSlider undefined after adding via yarn to existing project
This is my first time working with yarn, so it could be a dumb/simple question. I've added jquery using yarn add jquery and I can see it in the modules folder, and also in the package.json and yarn.lock files. I added type="module" to the script tag and then added this to the top of my js file:
import jquery from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = jquery;

That got rid of jQuery not being defined. So now I'm trying to add bxSlider which was done successfully. Again, I see everything where it should be, but when I try to import it, I get this error: @parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'bxslider'.
Here are the dependencies:
  "dependencies": {
    "@justinribeiro/lite-youtube": "^1.4.0",
    "bxslider": "^4.2.17",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1"
  }

If I remove the import line, it builds successfully, but then bxSlider isn't defined (as expected). What am I missing?
